# How to get number of issues in user's repo for pagination with Github API?

Tags: reactjs, github-api

So my task is to get all the issues from user's repo.

For that I'm doing this

```
axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}/issues?state=all`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

The problem is that I also need to make pagination for the issues but the `response` doesn't have any information about number of issues. It only has array of issues. And only 30 first ones I think

I tried to use different path for that, for exmaple the search one

```
axios.get(`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=${user}+${repo}&per_page=10`)
```

But it gives me completly different results issues wise although it does return total count.

All the help will be much appreciated.

For easy exmaple to make an api request you can use `Facebook` as user param and `React` as repo param

Answer (score 0):

Looks like github provides a Link header that will offer your that information:
https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

> The Link header includes pagination information:

```
Link: <https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=3&per_page=100>; rel="next",
  <https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=50&per_page=100>; rel="last"
```

Comment: Yeah but how will I know how much pages there are to display in pagination?

Comment: I checked the headers of response and there is a header with ```last``` which shows the number of the last page ```<https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=50&per_page=100>; rel="last"```. But I'm not sure how I supposed to use that as my pagination. Like I suppose to parse this string to get the number? It is strange.

Comment: If github does not provide the information in any other way (which I did not see either, only open issues count via user repository listing https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories), then I guess this is the way to go. If you know there are 50 pages with x amount of entries & on which page you are currently, you can easily create your pagination.

Answer (score -1):

Example react js repo:
https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/issues
with pagination:
https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/issues?page=2

Read [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) for more options

```
axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}/issues?page=${page}&per_page=10`)
   .then((response) => {
     console.log(response);
   })
   .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

**v4 With GraphQL**

Read this [article](https://dev.to/thomasaudo/get-started-with-github-grapql-api--1g8b)

GraphQL query:

```
query { 
  repository(owner:"facebook", name:"react") { 
    issues(states:OPEN) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but how will I know how much pages there are to display in pagination?

Comment: may be try to use v4 with graphql?